# Prolog, skip adding elements to a list based on rules

Tags: list, recursion, filter, prolog

I have some Prolog code, and would like to be able to skip adding an element to the Results list if the product of X and Y is greater than a certain value. Any idea how I would go about doing this?

e.g.

```
if Product > 10
```

The code I have so far

```
make_quads(_,[],[]).
make_quads(X,[Y|TAIL],[[X,Y,Sum,Product]|Result]):-
    make_quads(X,TAIL,Result),
    Product is X * Y,
    Product > 2,
    Sum is X + Y.
```

The function is called as follows:

```
?- make_quads(5, [1,2,3,4,5,6], X).
```

Which would give the following output:

```
X = [[5, 1, 6, 5], [5, 2, 7, 10], [5, 3, 8, 15], [5, 4, 9, 20], [5, 5, 10, 25], [5, 6, 11|...]]
```

I've tried something along the lines of the following, but SWI-Prolog returns false as soon as I call the function

```
make_quads(_,[],[]).
make_quads(X,[Y|TAIL],[[X,Y,Sum,Product]|Result]):-
    make_quads(X,TAIL,Result),
    Product is X * Y,
    Product > 20, % I need to skip here
    % Else continue running
    Sum is X + Y.
```

Comment: Your code seems to me missing the head to your second predicate clause or has some kind of typo. The second line reads, `make_quads(X,[Y|TAIL],[[X,Y,Sum,Product]|` so seems truncated? Also, as a point of terminology in Prolog, these are not *functions* but *predicates*.

Comment: Where in your code do you define what the *certain value* is that you don't want to exceed? Or do you plan to pass that as an argument to your predicate call?

Comment: I've updated the description which outlines what I've attempted already. I know the goal of Product > 20, needs to evaluate to True for the code below it to be reached. But I'm still unsure how I'd prevent the product and sum from being added to the Results list if the Product is a smaller value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already observed that the reason that your predicate fails is because it needs to succeed (not fail) if `Product =< 20`, but just not keep the values. As it stands, once your predicate fails on `Product > 20`, the entire predicate fails since it lacks such a clause

You're main clause needs to be split into two cases. The simple way to do this is to add another clause for the case where `Product =< 20`. Also, you can use tail recursion here, which can be optimized by some Prolog interpreters. No need to recurse before setting the values:

```
make_quads(_, [], []).
make_quads(X, [Y|TAIL], [[X,Y,Sum,Product] | Result]):-
    Product is X * Y,
    Product > 20,
    Sum is X + Y,
    make_quads(X, TAIL, Result).
make_quads(X, [Y|TAIL], Result):-
    Product is X * Y,
    Product =< 20,
    make_quads(X, TAIL, Result).
```

You can also use the Prolog `->` operator, which is a little more efficient:

```
make_quads(_, [], []).
make_quads(X, [Y|TAIL], Result):-
    Product is X * Y,
    (   Product > 20
    ->  Sum is X + Y,                   % Do this if Product > 20
        Result = [[X,Y,Sum,Product]|R]
    ;   Result = R                      % Do this if Product =< 20
    ),
    make_quads(X, TAIL, R).
```

Comment: Many thanks for your patience and your help! (I'd upvote your answer if I had the karma). Cheers, Jack

Comment: @JackEvans glad it helped. You may not be able to upvote, but you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark. :)